# Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to render names that are in the State. But I get this error:
`Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.` I understand that ReactNode can't be assigned to an object, but is there any alternative to ReactNode, or what is the best practice?

Thank you in advance, it is my fist time doing something in React and TypeScript

Here is my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

interface State {
  monster1: {
    name: string;
  };
  monster2: {
    name: string;
  };
  monster3: {
    name: string;
  };
}

interface Props {}

class App extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      monster1: {
        name: "Linda",
      },

      monster2: {
        name: "Frank",
      },

      monster3: {
        name: "Jacky",
      },
    };
  }

  override render(): JSX.Element {
    {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div>
            <h1>{this.state.monster1}</h1>
            <h1>{this.state.monster2}</h1>
            <h1>{this.state.monster3}</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.state.monster1` is an object with a property `name`. React does not allow you to render objects. You should access the `name` property (which hold a renderable string) instead:

```
<h1>{this.state.monster1.name}</h1>
<h1>{this.state.monster2.name}</h1>
<h1>{this.state.monster3.name}</h1>
```

Comment: Is there any possibility just render some json or something like that? Is there some type for that in react?

Comment: You could always use `JSON.stringify()` to convert an object to a string and display that

Answer (score 3):

You should simply be returning your JSX (not within an object). The reason that ur seeing this error output is because Typescript is essentially saying: "hey you told me that I should expect a JSX.Element to be returned, but you instead are returning something else (aka an object).

## With all that said the solution to your issue is:

```
override render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.monster1}</h1>
                <h1>{this.state.monster2}</h1>
                <h1>{this.state.monster3}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your render function should directly return the JSX you are trying to render:

```
override render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.monster1}</h1>
                <h1>{this.state.monster2}</h1>
                <h1>{this.state.monster3}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```